# ¿Por qué el body no abarca todo el alto de la pagina?

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de realizar un sticky footer, pero no funciona, me percate de que el body solo abarca la mitad de la pagina y no se porque, ya intente varios métodos para ocupe el 100% de alto pero ninguno me funciona.
No se si sea por los demás elementos que están en la pagina, pero dudo que sea por eso, lo raro es que hay elementos en la pagina que están fuera del tamaño del body, por lo que la verdad estoy muy confundido, ya que, según yo, eso tampoco debería de pasar

Este es mi código:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #000;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#header {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #ffc711;
  min-width: 100%;
}

#logo_header {
  height: 80px;
  margin: 15px 20px;
}

.info {
  display: inline-flex;
}

#info1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#info1 h3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

#info1 p {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

#info2 h3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12%;
}

#info2 p {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

#info3 h3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 33%;
}

#info3 p {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

#info4 h3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
}

#info4 p {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

#logo_whatsapp {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  right: 0;
}

.iconos {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 30px 13px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.iconos img {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.text p {
  text-align: center;
}

#contenido {
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 0;
}

.img-contenido {
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
}

#footer {
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
}

.redes_footer {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.redes {
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
}

@media(max-width: 512px) {
  .nav img {
    max-width: 512px;
  }
  #header {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"></link>
  <title>MWL</title>
</head>

<body>

  <main>

    <header id="header">

      <img src="IMAGENES MWL SERVICES/LOGO-FOOTER.png" alt="" id="logo_header">

    </header>

    
    <img src="IMAGENES MWL SERVICES/WHATSAPP.png" alt="" id="logo_whatsapp">

    <section class="text">


      <p>Brindamos soluciones practicas, eficaces y eficientes en temas de comercio internacional y lógistica especializada a través de un <b>servicio confiable, integral y personalizado</b>
      </p>


    <footer id="footer">

      <div>
        <img src="IMAGENES MWL SERVICES/LOGO-FOOTER.png" alt="" id="logo_footer">
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae nesciunt suscipit amet deserunt quos quod commodi adipisci consequuntur</p>

        <ul>
          <li class="redes_footer"><img src="IMAGENES MWL SERVICES/REDES FOOTER/FB.png" alt="" class="redes"></li>
          <li class="redes_footer"><img src="IMAGENES MWL SERVICES/REDES FOOTER/IG.png" alt="" class="redes"></li>
          <li class="redes_footer"><img src="IMAGENES MWL SERVICES/REDES FOOTER/YT.png" alt="" class="redes"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </footer>

  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Ya intente usando propiedades como `heigh:100%`, también con min-heigh y sigue sin funcionar, espero puedan ayudarme, gracias

Comment: El body en tu ejemplo si ocupa el alto de la página

Answer (score 0):

En realidad si esta ocupando el 100% del espacio, sin embargo no se muestra así porque los objetos dentro del main no están ocupando ese espacio, la forma mas fácil de hacer lo que quieres es agregar un header de x tamaño y un footer también de x tamaño y calcular el main basado en el tamaño del viewport menos la suma del header y footer usando la función calc, por ejemplo.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header,
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #1ABC9C;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
main {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: calc( 100vh - 100px );
  padding: 25px 50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h2>Header</h2>
</header>

<main>
  <h2>Main</h2>
</main>

<footer>
  <h2>Footer</h2>
</footer>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero me sigue sin funcionar